# Installing "C" on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, compiling

I typed the "Hello, World" program in the Ubuntu text editor.
The file, 'hello' was saved to the `documents` folder, which I verified, is there.

However, the "c" compiler, version 7.4.0-1, cannot find 'hello.'
Moreover, the program 'find' cannot find it either.
I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Save it to your Home directory. Otherwise you'll need to provide path to this file.

Comment: Would you post the commands you use, and the `ls` of you Documents/ directory?

Comment: @Pilot6 Why is that? I can compile a file in a subdir without a full path.

Comment: Anyway you need some path. You can't compile file `hello` in your Documents by running `gcc hello`.

Comment: @Pilot6 But I can do it?

Comment: `adminred@adminred:~/Documentos$ gcc foo.c` and `a.out foo.c`

Comment: @guillermochamorro You run it form a directory where is you file located. OP is running from `~`.

Comment: Ah, yes, as OP didn't mention from where he is issuing the command I just assumed he was on the same directory and hence I thought you too, but also he says that `find` can't find the file...

Comment: OP wrote that he created the file in Documents using text editor, then opened a terminal and tried to compile. So gcc didn't know where to look. So either a path, or cd.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Make sure you are in the same directory in terminal as is your file `hello.c`. Type `cd /path/to/your_folder/` in terminal to go to it.

Then, `gcc hello.c -o helloout` should compile it to the output file `helloout`. To execute the compiled code, type `./helloout`.

**Note:** If I left the code file `hello` without the `.c` extension, gcc says

```
file not recognized: Unrecognized file format
```

Follows the example I tested (`hello.c`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello, World\n");
    return 0;
}
```